# Create a user and password from a file using python in ubuntu

Tags: python

I have been asked to create a user and password from two files in ubuntu. Below is what i did in python.

```py
import os

with open("users.txt",'r') as file, open("passwords.txt", 'r') as password:
    for line in file:
        pass
        for passw in password:
            os.system('useradd ' +line)
            os.system('echo +line +passw | chpasswd')
```

*Contents of users.txt*

```
avinash
ananthram
```

*Contents of passwords.txt*

```
lifeisbeautiful
lifeisbeautifulagain
```

It gives me an error in the last line saying `chpasswd: line 1: missing new password`. I have tried using `os.system("echo +line +passw | chpasswd")` but still it gives me the error. Can someone help me through this? Thanks in advance

I am expecting to create users with the password from two files.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. In your own words, where the code says `os.system('echo +line +passw | chpasswd')
`, exactly what do you expect this to mean? Specifically, *what do you think the command line will see?* Are you trying to make it so that the Python variables `line` and `passw`, will be inserted into the shell command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You have to loop through the lines in both files simultaneously. Code you provided reads the first line from user file, then loops through all the passwords trying to set those passwords for the first user. By the time you reach read second line in users file you have already reached EOF in password file.
2. Substitute `line` and `passw` in last command with those variables' values.
3. `chpasswd` expects user and password delimited by colon, not space
4. add `-n` to `echo` to suppress adding newline character at the end

```python
import os

with open("users.txt",'r') as file, open("passwords.txt", 'r') as password:
    for line, passw in zip(file, password):
        os.system('useradd ' +line)
        os.system(f'echo -n "{line}:{passw}" | chpasswd')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
os.system(f'echo -e "{line}\n{passw}" | chpasswd')
```

**Explanation** - The echo command is used to write a string to the standard output, but you are using it to construct the command that you want to pass to chpasswd.
Instead of using echo, you can use the -e option of echo to include a new line in the string being passed to chpasswd.

Comment: thank you..but now it says "missing new password" error. seems like the passw variable is not reading.

Comment: Try printing the values of line and passw before passing them to the chpasswd command to see if they contain the expected values.

Comment: Make sure that the line variable should only contain the username, not the full useradd command.

Comment: i checked it but it seems like the user is not read properly from the file. only the first user name is fetched not the second one..the password values are okay.. i think there is some issues with my looping

Comment: If the problem stated in the question is resolved then accept it as a correct answer. The loop-related problem if still persists can be asked in a separate question.